# Find Value in Array Comparing To Index

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I am learning C# on my own and came across a question where i got stuck.
I need to find value of array based on input from user.

```
string[] arr = new string[6];
            arr[0] = "Us";
            arr[1] = "Canada";
            arr[2] = "Uk";
            arr[3] = "China";
            arr[4] = "India";
            arr[5] = "Korea";

Console.WriteLine("Choose a Country (or -1 to quit):");
```

Now if user enter's 3 it will select China.

I am confused how to **compare user input with index and get that value**.

I tried, but does not seem to work :(

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int arrayindex = Array.IndexOf(arr,number);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused how to compare user input with index and get that value

You can use indexer to get the value at particular index of the array you have.

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string country = arr[number]; // This will give you China
```

If you want to make sure user gives the number that is valid array index then you can apply condition before using indexer that it should be 0 or one less then the length of an array.

```
if(number > -1 && number < arr.Length)
     country = arr[number];
```

Comment: Thanks. But how would i compare input number with index?

Comment: Why you want to compare number with index to check if exists as index of array?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a range, just check if the input value is within the range. In this case

```
if (inputvalue >= 0 && inputvalue <= 6) 
  string country = arr[inputValue] // to get the actual content
else
  //invalid input --provided it is not -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code which does the thing you want - However this code does not handle error cases if you enter string or special character...

```
using System;

namespace TestConcept
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string countryCodeStr;
            int contryCodeInt;
            string[] arr = new string[6];
            arr[0] = "Us";
            arr[1] = "Canada";
            arr[2] = "Uk";
            arr[3] = "China";
            arr[4] = "India";
            arr[5] = "Korea";

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose a Country Code from 0-5 (or -1 to quit):");
                countryCodeStr = Console.ReadLine();
                contryCodeInt = Convert.ToInt32(countryCodeStr);
                switch (contryCodeInt)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Selected Country :" + arr[0]);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Selected Country :" + arr[1]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Selected Country :" + arr[2]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Selected Country :" + arr[3]);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Selected Country :" + arr[4]);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Selected Country :" + arr[5]);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection. Please select -1 to 5");
                        break;
                }
            } while (contryCodeInt != -1);

            if (contryCodeInt == -1)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```